# How does backbone.js work with CoffeeScript?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, integration

Are there any inherent problems with using CoffeeScript to code backbone.js apps? Did you run into some problems that you couldn't fix or had to use some particularly clunky workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript is just a syntax layer on top of JavaScript. It essentially is JavaScript. Anything you can do in JavaScript you can reproduce in CoffeeScript.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/91. I'm wondering if there are other problems with CoffeeScript and backbone integration.

Answer (score 6):

No problems, really.  At least, none that aren't easily worked around.

The problems with using CS are the same problems you might get using CS anywhere:

- Debugging is still done in the generated JS
- CS requires a pre-processing step that can be awkward at times
- The rest of your team might not know CS
- There are some odd things about CS (they introduce "classes" but they are not real classes)

In addition, since Backbone dev with Coffeescript is "class" based, you find yourself wanting to separate your classes into separate files, in separate folders.  Because of this, you can get into a situation where the classes are defined out of order.  For instance, your collection might get defined before your model, which can't happen.  For this, I recommend using something that can manage dependencies (imports).  I use [coffee-toaster](https://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster) but there are several other options (Rails has dependency management built in to the asset pipeline, for instance)

It is my preferred way to write Backbone code.  In my opinion, Backbone.js development is actually better in CoffeeScript than in Javascript.  To me, they go together like chocolate and peanut butter.  (Not everyone likes chocolate/peanut butter... not everyone likes BB/CS)

**Class semantics**
Backbone development relies heavily on extending prototypes and this is something that is built-in with CoffeeScript.  So, where you would extend a View in JS:

```
App.Models.MyModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

The CS alternative is a native experience:

```
class App.Models.MyModel extends Backbone.Model
    render: ->
        ...
```

**Overriding Functions**
Some things you do often in Backbone, like overriding functions becomes much more simple.  In Javascript:

```
constructor: function ( attributes, options ) {
    this.constructor.__super__.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    ...
}
```

Becomes:

```
constructor: (attributes, options) ->
    super
```

**"this" Context Binding**
The "fat arrow" in CS is really useful when you need to declare the context of a function is "this"

Javascript sets 'this' differently when functions get called back.  There are several ways to solve it, but out of the box, it is awkward:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('reset', this.render);
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html("<ul></ul>");
    this.model.each(this.renderItem); // <--- Fails on "reset" because 'this' is wrong
    return this;
}
```

CoffeeScript has the `=>` token that will automatically bind 'this' to the function when it gets called by anybody:

```
initialize: ->
    @model.bind 'reset', @render

render: =>
    @$el.html '<ul></ul>'
    @model.each @renderItem  # The fat arrow fixed it for you
    @
```

When all is said and done, Backbone.js code is easier to write and is much easier to read when written in CS.  At least, that is my opinion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Both CoffeeScript and Backbone.js were written by the same author (Jeremy Ashkenas). The [backbone-on-rails](https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails) gem generates CoffeeScript by default. Though certain plugins (such as Backbone-relational, which you mentioned) may require additional setup, Backbone itself plays very nicely with CoffeeScript.